# Lotus IBM Notes 9

Tags: lotus-notes

I would like to count the number of emails sent and name of associates who have sent an email from a specific common sent items.

It take ages for me to count the number of emails sent and to segregate the name of the associates.

Please help me to create a lotus notes script which will perform the above two steps and store in excel.

As always thank you so much for your help.

Sumit

Comment: Please create the solution on your own (at least try it) and ask here for help if you have issues with your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not relate to a specific problem in existing code. It is asking others to provide code for an entire solution.

Comment: Write a title that summarizes the specific problem. On this question it does not explain what the problem is, it is just a generic subject.
Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code that you wrote, then it is easier for us to help.

I suspect that your code is slow because you did not write it for performance. First of all, make sure you don't use GetNthDocument(). Second, if you are iterating through a view, use a NotesViewEntryCollection to get the NotesViewEntries. You read the values using the ColumnValues property of the NotesViewEntry class. That will make your code much faster than if you open each document.
You can read more about this here: http://blog.texasswede.com/re-using-lotusscript-lists-to-increase-performance/

Next you use a list to store the number of documents per person/address. That is fast and efficient.
You can read more about list here: http://blog.texasswede.com/sntt-lists-the-forgotten-gem-in-lotusscript/